# Return already read and unread rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables, where in the first I have procedures and in the second I register the users who read them according to the click on the procedures:

```
CREATE TABLE Faq ( id INT, Titulo varchar(30) );
INSERT INTO Faq VALUES
(1, 'Teste'),
(2, 'Teste1'),
(3, 'Teste2'),
(4, 'Teste3'),
(5, 'Teste4');

CREATE TABLE LeituraFaq( id INT, Id_Faq INT, leitura INT, Colaborador INT );
INSERT INTO LeituraFaq VALUES
(1, 3, 1, 19),
(2, 5, 1, 19),
(1, 3, 1, 24),
(1, 2, 1, 24);
```

What I intend with the two tables is to understand the procedures that each one has already read and the procedures that still have to be read.

I have the following query that returns what each contributor has already read, like this:

```
SELECT Faq.id, Titulo, LeituraFaq.Colaborador, leitura 

FROM Faq LEFT OUTER JOIN LeituraFaq ON LeituraFaq.Id_Faq = Faq.id

WHERE LeituraFaq.Colaborador = '19'
```

In addition to the procedures already read, I also need the query to return the procedures that each user has not yet read.

The result I want for example for the user with id 19:

```
id  Titulo  Colaborador leitura
1   Teste
2   Teste1
3   Teste2    19           1
4   Teste3
5   Teste4    19           1
```

It means that the user with id 19 has already read two procedures and has 3 to read. This is the intended result. The result must be dynamic and per user.

Here is an example of what I have:

[example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dji5M2bhBrQZq8hjhrxg9t/3)

Comment: Provide desired output for shown sample data with detailed explanations for each output row.

Comment: ??? You tell "But I need the query to return the procedures that each collaborator **has not yet read**" whereas your desired output contains the output rows for tests 2 and 4 which are already read.

Comment: @Akina Yes, but if it is possible to return read and unread messages in the same query, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need in either

```
SELECT t2.Colaborador, t1.Titulo
FROM Faq t1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Colaborador
    FROM LeituraFaq
    ) t2
LEFT JOIN LeituraFaq t3 ON t3.Id_Faq = t1.id AND t3.Colaborador = t2.Colaborador
WHERE t3.id IS NULL
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

or

```
SELECT t2.Colaborador, GROUP_CONCAT(t1.Titulo)
FROM Faq t1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Colaborador
    FROM LeituraFaq
    ) t2
LEFT JOIN LeituraFaq t3 ON t3.Id_Faq = t1.id AND t3.Colaborador = t2.Colaborador
WHERE t3.id IS NULL
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Explanation.

Subquery `t2` gathers complete Colaborador list.

Cross join with `t1` produces all possible pairs (Titulo-Colaborador).

`LEFT JOIN t3` with further `WHERE .. IS NULL` selects all above pairs which have no according row in `t3` table.

If the table which stores complete Colaborador list exists then you'd use it instead of subquery `t2`.

---

> if it is possible to return read and unread messages in the same query, that would be ideal. - Bruno

```
SELECT t1.Titulo,
       COALESCE(t2.Colaborador, '') Colaborador,
       COALESCE(t2.leitura, '') leitura
FROM Faq t1
LEFT JOIN LeituraFaq t2 ON t2.Id_Faq = t1.id AND t2.Colaborador = 19
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `LEFT JOIN` to join your tables, then use `GROUP BY` and `MAX CASE WHEN` to get your desired output as follows :

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT f.id, f.Titulo, lf.Colaborador, lf.leitura 
  FROM Faq f
  LEFT JOIN LeituraFaq lf ON lf.Id_Faq = f.id
)
select id, MAX(Titulo), MAX(CASE WHEN Colaborador = 19 THEN Colaborador END) AS Colaborador,
max(CASE WHEN Colaborador = 19 THEN leitura END) AS leitura
from cte
group by id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/xEeNIT4P)

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: True, You solution is better than mine :)